# Possible to somehow hide a childNode in Treeview?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

is it possible to somehow create an extension of TreeView. Allowing me to hide a specific childnode in treeview?

When UnHiding it should then return to its previous location.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a child node visible = false in a Treeview Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253244/how-to-make-a-child-node-visible-false-in-a-treeview-control)

Comment: @OlivierRogier seems like it does. But a little bit confused on how to use this extension