# How to hide a specific node on treeview in c# winform?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a treeview and i want to hide a node or a child node.
Any solutions , please help.

Comment: [No way](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0d795201-7ed0-444e-89b9-d85d2d46b4bc/treeview-hide-a-node?forum=winforms) short of [removing and re-inserting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253244/how-to-make-a-child-node-visible-false-in-a-treeview-control) it..

Comment: Thanks for helping !! It's useful. I use this method and it works